# read.csv is shifting column names to the right in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I'm trying to import a csv file and skip the first few lines of metadata as follows:

`df <- read.csv("file.csv",skip = 8)`

The resultant .csv file when exported has all headers shifted to the right by one and an extra column of NAs introduced to the data. Examining the output in notepad shows that R introduced a blank header which looks like `"","header1","header2"`

If I open the original file in notepad and remove the first few lines of metadata manually and import to R it works fine. Also there are no commas or inverted commas in the metadata. 
Why is the skip function introducing a blank column and is there another way to remove the metadata?

Metadata looks like this:

```
Line 1 text

Line 3 text
Line 4 text

Column1, Column2, Column3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can imagine it is difficult to troubleshoot without having the CSV. It is possible that the first 8 lines of the CSV that you are skipping have more columns then the rest of the file and the reader is inserting more columns than needed. You can try to trim the file after reading.